# Xcode 6.4 update fail

Tags: macos, updates, xcode

I tried to update my Xcode with App Store and it says that Xcode is updated, but actually, when I run Xcode, runs previous version 6.3.2. How can I update Xcode by hands?

Terminal:

```
xcodebuild -version
Xcode 6.3.2
Build version 6D2105

gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the command line tools?

Answer (score 0):

First check that the command line tool is pointing to the newer Xcode version. Go to Xcode > Preferences, Locations tab, and make sure the "Command Line Tools" dropdown is Xcode 6.4 (in your case).

You may also download and install the latest command line tools for your Xcode version from Apple Developer portal website.

If issue remains (which is unlikely), simply delete the old Xcode in your applications folder and install again. All you iOS simulators will not be deleted and you only need to download additional simulators that are available in the new versions.